# How do I find the root of the directory I'm currently in for Linux

Tags: linux, shell

like if I'm in a directory called makefile_assignment, what command would give me the higher up directories and display it like

/home/linux/ieng6/cs80w/public/makefile_assignment

Comment: Jamie, you're getting a lot of your questions closed as off-topic. Stack Overflow is about programming Q&A. You might be interested in one of our our sister sites, [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: this is not the "root of the directly I'm currently in" the root is always the same `/`. it is the `absolute path of  current dir (or working dir)`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for:

```
pwd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the environment variable of $PWD

```
echo $PWD
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pwd` command is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The command is `pwd` (present working directory).

Usually, `echo $PWD` also works and produces the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
pwd #present working directory
cd / #to your root directory
```